# WebRequest and protocol agnostic URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

In a web application I have to first check if  an image exists and then display this image or a dummy image.

I use the following code and it works for URLS like:

- "**http**://www.somedomain.com/niceimage.png"
- "**https**://www.somedomain.com/niceimage.png".

```
public virtual bool WebResourceExists(string url)
{
    WebHeaderCollection headers = null;
    WebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        response = request.GetResponse();
        headers = response.Headers;
        bool result = int.Parse(headers["Content-Length"]) > 0;
        return result;
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error(e);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In some places the the method is called with protocol agnostic urls like `"//www.somedomain.com/niceimage.png"`.

There is an exception thrown for such urls:

> `System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'`

Is there a way to use protocol agnostic urls other then just prepending `"http:"` to the url?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are casting `WebRequest` to `HttpWebRequest` and `WebResponse` to `HttpWebResponse`?

Comment: No there is no reason for it. I updated the code sample.

Comment: The behaviour is not changed when no casting to HttpWebRequest is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocol-agnostic URLs are resolved by the browser using the current protocol, and are used to avoid making HTTP requests from an HTTPS page.

Code executing on the server doesn't really have a concept of a "current protocol". Whilst ASP.NET can determine whether the current request was issued over HTTP or HTTPS, the `WebRequest` classes are not restricted to ASP.NET applications, so they cannot rely on this.

You will need to specify the protocol. Whether you use HTTP or HTTPS will depend on whether you're concerned about third-parties eavesdropping on the connection between your server and "www.somedomain.com".

Answer (score 0):

What about a two step process, check for the http version, if it doesn't exist check for https. I've quickly hacked together a basic example of how this could work but am not able to properly test and check it so it might need some tidying up/refactoring!

```
public virtual bool WebResourceExists(string url)
{
    WebHeaderCollection headers = null;
    WebResponse response = null;
    try
    {
        if (url.StartsWith(@"//") {
           url = "http:";
        }
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        response = request.GetResponse();
        headers = response.Headers;
        bool result = int.Parse(headers["Content-Length"]) > 0;
        return result;
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException)
    {
        if (url.StartsWith(@"http://") {
           url = url.Replace("http://","https://");
        } else {
           return false;
        }
        try {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            response = request.GetResponse();
           headers = response.Headers;
           bool result = int.Parse(headers["Content-Length"]) > 0;
           return result;
       }
       catch (System.Net.WebException)
       {
            return false;
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Error(e);
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```